# Desktop view its showing the text but in mobile view the text is not showing

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am student , am trying to use Bootstrap Carousel Plugin, And am using this [ https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/7B4x ] carousel example, in desktop view its showing the text but in mobile view the text is not showing. can any please help me.

Comment: Provided link is broken, please post here the relevant part of the code

Comment: Hi @abidibo, updated the link.

Comment: You are required to post your code here, NEVER any third party site. [mcve] And your earlier broken link is a best example why this question will eventually be closed and deleted.

Comment: Sorry  @Rob ,I am new one to this site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have added the `hidden-xs` class to your divs (lines 21, 39 and 57).

This Bootstrap 3 class hides your element and its children in mobile view. You just have to remove this class to show it in any situation.

[This doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#responsive-utilities-classes) may help you understand how Bootstrap 3 `hidden` classes work.

Answer (score 0):

@chethan the reason for not showing text in the carousel is that is has been hidden by the `.hidden-xs` of Bootstrap-3.4

The property specifies that on all xs size devices Extra small devices
[ Phones (<768px) ] hide the text.
here is [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#responsive-utilities-classes) on the hidden property of bootstrap for your understanding.